# Scrapy cutting off long strings

Tags: python, string, xpath, scrapy

I want to extract text data from forum posts. This is my working spider:

```
import scrapy
import csv #not used yet


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes2"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.motor-talk.de/faq/mercedes-e-klasse-w210-q89.html#Q3512477',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        xString= ' '
        xStringLink = ' '

        for i in range(4, 6): # start, stop
            xString='//*[@id="questions"]/div[2]/div['+str(i)+']/div[2]/div[1]/table/tr/td/div/text()'
            xStringLink='//*[@id="questions"]/div[2]/div['+str(i)+']/a/@name'

            scraped_info = {
                'forum post': response.xpath(xString).extract(),
                'link': response.xpath(xStringLink).extract()
            }
            yield scraped_info
```

However, I only get the following output: As you can see, the forum posts are cut off :(  :

```
(...)
2017-11-19 15:52:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.motor-talk.de/faq/mercedes-e-klasse-w210-q89.html#Q3512477> (referer: None)
2017-11-19 15:52:30 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.motor-talk.de/faq/mercedes-e-klasse-w210-q89.html>
{'forum post': ['BR210, alle Modelle mit Hersteller-Schlüssel-Nr., Typ-Schlüssel-Nr., Stückzahlen CDI Common-Rail...'], 'link': ['Q3594587']}
2017-11-19 15:52:30 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.motor-talk.de/faq/mercedes-e-klasse-w210-q89.html>
{'forum post': ['Als Neujahrs-Gruß nachfolgend eine Aufstellung der Fahrgestell-Indent-Nummern, sortiert nach Prod...'], 'link': ['Q5160969']}
2017-11-19 15:52:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
(...)
```

In reality, the posts are much longer, but the strings simply get cut off.

Comment: Its because you need to log in to the forum to see the full posts. Without signing in, you are only able to see snippets. You'll need to have your spider log in.

Comment: Ahhhh Thanks! That explains it. Do you hava any idea how I get my spider to log in?

Comment: Output shows log messages and they can be shortened intentionally because they are too long to display. Save data in file (with option `-o`) and see what you get. Or at least use `print()` in `parse()` to display full.

Comment: Well I don't use scrapy for web scraping, but here's the docs for logging in: [scrapy docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-userlogin)

Comment: @furas It's definitely bc of the logging in, i get the same mistake if I save in a file.

Comment: To Login you could either manually code the spider to login, by reproducing the request sent when logging in or use the [loginform](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2012/10/26/filling-login-forms-automatically/)